# Prevent notification emails when I update an issue?

Tags: mantis

We're using the latest version (1.2.19) of MantisBT and it seems really silly that I get notification emails when I update an issue created by myself and assigned by myself.

I know the issue changed, Mantis, I'm the one who changed it. You don't need to email me.

I found this link: https://www.mantisbt.org/manual/admin.customize.email.html

But it doesn't seem to offer what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g_mail_receive_own controls this behaviour. Make sure it is OFF in your config file